# Make Synchronous in ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, call, synchronous

in my script i have an ajax call to a php file and i would like to have the call completed before the rest of the script below gets executed

Here is the script i am referring to:

```
function game_settings(state){
    if(state == "load"){
        ui.load_game();

        //do ajax call to load user last save
        var dataString = {"user_data": "true"};
        $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
            url:"PHP/class.ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(success) {
                    player_details_init(success)
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("ERROR in User data");
            }
        });

        console.log (player_level);
        //scene.load("level_"+level);

        //instantiate a heroObject
        player = new Player(20,20,game_width, game_height);
        // set it's image to the proper src URL
        player.image.src = "images/Mage_Sprite.png";
        // once the image has completed loading, render it to the screen
        player.image.onload = function()
        {
            player.render();
        };

        lastUpdate = Date.now();
    }
```

SO for instance right now when the script runs, i can see in console that the ajax request gets made, and then the rest of the script gets execute before the ajax has finished resulting in this call:

```
console.log (player_level);
```

to return undefined rather then the value it should be because the ajax hasn't completed.

To clarify my question is:

How should i make the ajax call finish before the rest of the script gets processed?

Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) explains, very clearly, how to make a request synchronous.

Comment: Synchronous ajax is generally considered to be a bad thing for the user experience, as it freezes the browser while waiting for the response. Except in unusual circumstances (can't even think of one offhand), it's much better to code for asynchronous ajax.

Comment: @Pointy For `unload` callbacks, your ajax call must be synchronous or it doesn't fire. Think of those as situations were you want the server to know the "user is logging off" or something.

Comment: @BradM ok that's a good "unusual circumstance" :-)

Comment: @Pointy what other methods would you suggest? thanks

Comment: @TomBurman do the request asynchronously. Just put the code that needs to run after the request completes inside the "success" callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put the rest of the script in the success callback of the AJAX call, or set the `async` property of the AJAX call config to false, which will make it synchronous.

Comment: What??? No No, don't make your ajax synchronous unless it's absolutely required and you know the full ramifications.

Comment: @BradM, he asked, I answered. As for the ramifications... if he wants to halt the execution of all scripts on his page...up to him.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Your solution is perfect, it's just that in all likeliness, making it synchronous is not the best solution for the OP's problem.

Comment: @BradM it just seems like your solution is a for the time being soltuion, are there any others?

Answer (score 4):

Put the "rest of the script" inside the success callback function.